# Optimizing a certain query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a query that goes such:

bankNumber and BIC are both indexed.

```
SELECT * FROM `bank1` WHERE `bankNumber` <= 200000 or `BIC` = 'Berlin'
```

By using the `EXPLAIN`, it uses both of the keys in `possible_keys`. I read in an article that one of the things that not to do when queries for indicies is to use OR.

I am tasked to optimize this query so that only one key gets used in the execution strategy.
What should I do in this case?

Things that I've tried:

Obviously went for AND, that did give me the desired result from `EXPLAIN`, but the data results are completely different.

Comment: Do you really need all columns?

Comment: Yes, I do need all the columns.

Comment: Often a *union* can provide better performance, depending on the indexes and the cardinality of the data.

Comment: I will give union a try, see if EXPLAIN gives the wanted result and the data also matches. Thanks for the suggestion @Stu

Comment: Please show us the `EXPLAIN`; it sounds like it used "Index merge union".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND obviously will produce different results.  The only way to use indexes would be to union:

```
select bank1.* from (
    select id from bank1 where bankNumber <= 200000
    union distinct
    select id from bank1 where BIC='Berlin'
) ids
join bank1 on bank1.id=ids.id
```

But I question your entire goal; is the query in fact too slow?  It doesn't seem like you would have enough bank rows that a full table scan would be that bad.

Comment: In the course, we are practicing on some databases and we were given a .csv to be imported and data is up in the 500000's or something. Not sure myself if it's slow but this was a task given regardless, to be honest.

Comment: Your code cleared up some stuff in my mind, thanks for this!